# Плавные эффекты jquery

Tags: jquery

Делал давно сайт http://artpk.net/ , пытался сделать плавные эффекты при наведении на выпадающее меню.

```
$('li').has('ul').mouseover(function()
{
    $(this).children('ul').show();
}).mouseout(function()
{
    $(this).children('ul').hide();
});
```

Если ставлю show(200) то при наведении меню ведёт себя неадекватно, просто show() нормально. Сейчас тоже столкнулся с тем что нужно сделать плавное меню, но до сих пор не понял как сделать чтобы он вёл себя нормально. Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Как по мне так нормальное меню.

Comment: да меню нормальное. но хочется чтоб всплывало медленно, а не появлялось резко)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуй использовать `.stop()`.

```
$('li').has('ul').mouseover(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().show(300);
    }).mouseout(function(){
    $(this).children('ul').stop().hide(300);
    });
```

И вот рабочий пример [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oburejin/heUYB/2/)

ПРАВКА:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oburejin/heUYB/6/) пример с 2мя пунктами меню.

Comment: а если так: [http://jsfiddle.net/heUYB/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/heUYB/3/)

Comment: И так все отлично работает, ты не повесил float: left; на второй пункт меню. http://jsfiddle.net/oburejin/heUYB/4/

Не надо путать людей =)

Comment: ваш "пример с 2мя пунктами меню." вообще нерабочий, потому что селектор `li > ul` не эквивалентен `$('li').has('ul')`

Comment: Ошибся ссылкой. Поправил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

```
  $('li').hover(function(){

     $('ul:first',this).slideToggle();

  });​
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shanhaichik/AhSET/1/

Comment: .stop() все-равно надо повесить, иначе анимации будут складываться. Попробуй быстро поводить по пунктам.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо за .stop() вешаю его перед началом анимации, и она адекватно себя ведёт!!! Ура! Я счастлив! Спасибо!